# Changing Device date and reseting back to the correct date still keeps the testflight build Expired

Tags: ios, testflight

I am currently testing an app via testflight. As there is a limit of 90 days for testing an app and after which the testflight App is expired and can't be tested further.

when I change the device date to the future date which is greater than 90 days, opening the app shows test flight expired. Which is the expected behaviour.

However when I change date back to the current valid date which is less than 90 days of expiration. The app still shows the TestFlight has Expired.

I want to understand if this is the correct behaviour or not, as I cant find any related question.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.  Once iOS has detected an expired provisioning profile, it is flagged as such.  Changing the date back will not remove the flag.  This is precisely to prevent people from "winding back the clock" in order to run an expired build.  I haven't seen this documented anywhere, it is simply from observation, but you can see why it makes sense.

Comment: Thankyou @Paulw11 for your answer, your point is valid. But Apple should look out to some better approach to handle the valid date scenarios.

Comment: What would be "better"?  That they allow turning back the date to access expired builds?

Comment: They might check the actual current date (may be from some server or whatever) and also the device date and if both are valid then let the app open else make it expired. However in that case the device date and actual date should be same then only user can access the app.  (Consider actual date is always valid)*

Comment: @Yaseen, in that case, you won't be able to test your app for future dates.

Comment: Yes that is true @ummerakbar you wont be able to test that expired app again.